# Treating graded rings and modules as sequences of abelian groups connected by maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, graded-rings, graded-modules

I've been reading about $\mathbb{Z}$-graded rings and modules recently and have attempted to understand these as sequences of abelian groups with connecting maps $A_i\times M_j\to M_{i+j}$ etc. This approach seems to be rather cumbersome the way I'm doing it compared to regarding them as actual rings and modules, so I might have got the wrong idea.

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places but everywhere I look they are defined simply via direct sum decompositions, and I can't find any systematic treatment of this topic using the 'sequence of abelian groups' approach. Where can I read about this?

Here is how I have defined a graded-commutative ring (I am working in characteristic two for the moment): For each $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, an abelian group $A_i$ and for each $i,j$, a biadditive map $\pi_{ij}:A_i\times A_j\to A_{i+j}$ for which $$\pi_{i+j,k}(\pi_{ij}(a,b),c)=\pi_{i,j+k}(a,\pi_{jk}(b,c)),$$ $$\pi_{0i}(1,a)=a,$$ $$\pi_{ij}(a,b)=\pi_{ji}(b,a).$$ (Note that $\pi_{00}$ is a ring multiplication on $A_0$, so the $1$ here is based on the additional requirement that $A_0$ is unital.)

Comment: Where does the requirement of the sign come from? It seems to me that this would make the ring of polynomials not be graded using the usual grading by degree.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That choice was motivated by the convention in the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf (right at beginning of introduction) however my main concern is with $\mathbb{F}_2$-graded algebras, so you could ignore the sign here.. edited accordingly

Comment: Actually, your choice of sign can only work if all products between degree-1 terms is zero, which is definitely not usual for a graded ring. Once you remove that (and fix the precise statement about the element $1\in A_0$ since it is not quite right currently), then translating between the two ways of viewing a graded ring should be quite straightforward.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What is wrong with the statement about $1\in A_0$?

Comment: You said that you required $A_0$ to be unital, but in your definition, it is just an abelian group, so that does not make sense. All you need to do is require that it has an element $1$ with the given property though.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The $\pi_{00}$ is a ring multiplication, so $A_0$ becomes a ring.

Comment: The map allows you to view it as a ring, sure.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft This sign convention makes it a [graded-commutative ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded-commutative_ring).

Comment: @red_trumpet Ahh, the OP was missing the hyphen, and somehow I didn't realize that.

Comment: The sign should definitely be restored, or please make clear that you are working in characteristic two.

Answer (score 1):

The paper "[On the Structure of Hopf Algebras](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970615)" by Milner and Moore (Ann. Math. 1965) takes this approach. See Section 1.